# Zend Framework 2: PostService::savePost() must be compatible with Blog\Service\PostServiceInterface::savePost(Blog\Model\PostInterface $blog) issue

Tags: zend-framework2

I am facing this issue while adding blog post in Zend Framework 2 using the link [Making use of Forms and Fieldsets](https://zf2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/in-depth-guide/zend-form-zend-form-fieldset.html). I have double checked whether anything is missed by me. Can anybody help where i am going wrong or anything missing please. As i am new Zend Framework its little hard to track the issue.

```
Fatal error: Declaration of Blog\Service\PostService::savePost() must be compatible with Blog\Service\PostServiceInterface::savePost(Blog\Model\PostInterface $blog) in D:\xampp\htdocs\zf\module\Blog\src\Blog\Service\PostService.php on line 9
```

The required file to fix this bug is given below:

```
<?php

 // Filename: /module/Blog/src/Blog/Service/PostService.php

  namespace Blog\Service;
```

> **use Blog\Model\PostInterface;**//this clause is missing in the [tutorial link](https://zf2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/in-depth-guide/zend-form-zend-form-fieldset.html)

```
  use Blog\Mapper\PostMapperInterface;

  class PostService implements PostServiceInterface {

   /**
   * @var \Blog\Mapper\PostMapperInterface
   */
   protected $postMapper;

   /**
    * @param PostMapperInterface $postMapper
    */
  public function __construct(PostMapperInterface $postMapper) {
    $this->postMapper = $postMapper;
    }

   /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
   public function findAllPosts() {
      return $this->postMapper->findAll();
   }

   /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
   public function findPost($id) {
      return $this->postMapper->find($id);
    }

    /**
    * {@inheritDoc}
    */
    public function savePost(PostInterface $post) {
      return $this->postMapper->save($post);
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I if saw correctly, it looks like that in the example you are following, in the `PostServiceClass`, a `use Blog\Model\PostInterface;` clause is missing.

This is causing the `PostInterface` used in the `savePost` method to be a `Blog\Service\PostInterface` and not a `Blog\Model\PostInterface` and hence the implementation of the `savePost` method is not complatible with its declaration in the interface